# Multiplying by a number in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, sequence

```
d = 2;
for x = [1:10]
    x
    d = ((2/d)*(sqrt(d^2+4)-2))
    d*(2^(x+1))
end
```

produces a sequence which tends to pi BUT,

```
d = 2;
for x = [1:10]
    x
    d = ((2/d)*(sqrt(d^2+4)-2)) * (2^(x+1))
end
```

does not. This gives a sequence (I've rounded a bit) : `3` , `9` , `25` , ... , `4E3`

What is going on? To me those lines look exactly the same.

Comment: In the first snippet `d*(2^(x+1))` is computed but is not used in the next iteration. In the second snippet that factor is part of the update applied to `d`

Comment: Oh, of course, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between these two is that for the first one, you multiply by d

```
d*(2^(x+1))
```

And every time it does a loop, the value of d is changed because of your whole equation. For the second code, 
  (2^(x+1))
you multiply by a constant 2 instead, which doesn't change every loop.

So  `d*(2^(x+1))` depends on d and x, but `(2^(x+1))` only depends on x.